# How to plot several columns of a matrix in the same plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a matrix called XY with the following entries:

```
0   1  1  3
2   4  2  3
4   2  3  5
6   2  5  6
```

I want to plot (in the same graph) columns 1 and 2 as the x and y axes respectively and columns 3 and 4 being the x and y axes respectively. I am trying the following code:

```
plot(XY[,1],XY[,2],type="l",col="red")
lines(XY[,3],XY[,4],col="green")
points(XY[,1],XY[,2],type="p",col="red")
points(XY[,3],XY[,4],type="p",col="green")
```

is there a more general way to do this graph without having to repeat the same code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind using `ggplot` rather than `base` plot (given the tags I think you don't), you can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

XY <- data.frame(XY)
colnames(XY)[1:4] <- c(paste0("var",1:4)) 
ggplot(data = XY) +
    geom_point(aes(x = var1, y = var2), color = "red") +
    geom_line(aes(x = var1, y = var2), color = "red") +
    geom_point(aes(x = var3, y = var4), color = "green") +
    geom_line(aes(x = var3, y = var4), color = "green")
```

The column name is a suggestion, maybe you have better variable names

## Update

In order to have a legend, long formatted data are easier to handle. You can try something like that:

```r
df <- rbind(
       cbind(XY[,c(1,2)], "group1"),
       cbind(XY[,c(3,4)], "group2")
      )
cols <- colnames(df)
```

Change *"group1"* and *"group2"* to relevent category names.

And you can plot like that:

```r
ggplot(data = df, aes_string(x = cols[1], y = cols[2], col = cols[3])) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line() +
    labs(color = "My colors")
```

I use `aes_string` because column names are quoted this time.

Comment: Thanks, it is very useful. Do you have a suggestion on how to add legends for the "red" set with a label for instance "Country" and the "green" set with a label "Time" for instance?

Comment: In your case, adding  `+ scale_colour_manual(name = 'the colour', values =c('green'='green','red'='red'), labels = c('c2','c1'))` to the above code might do the trick

Comment: I edited the answer to propose you another approach. It is easier to work with long formatted data in `ggplot` so if you want to customise your plot, the new snippets are better for you

Comment: the update you proposed above displays, for some reason, only the points but not the lines, I don't get any warning message from R though, another thing, should data be equal to "df" instead of "XY" inside ggplot?

Answer (score 1):

Try base R graphics `matplot` to avoid repeating code which both the base R and ggplot examples  in their own different ways do.

```
matplot(XY[,c(1, 3)], XY[,c(2, 4)], type = "l", lty = 1, col = c("red", "green"), pch = 1,
        xlab = "X label", ylab = "Y label")
matpoints(XY[,c(1, 3)], XY[,c(2, 4)], type = "p", pch = 1, col = c("red", "green"))
```

This gives you:

[image]